# Libgdx Choosing correct textures based on DPI?

Tags: android, libgdx

How to implement a system which takes the best texture based on dpi from a set like in android SDK, because LibGDX is platform independent, and can't use the already existent one?

Comment: You might want to take what you posted and distill it into something a bit more concentrated. Imagine you're writing an e-mail to your coworker. It is very hard for us to read paragraphs and paragraphs and figure out what you want. Give a couple of sentences of background, explain what you need to, then state your question explicitly. That way, it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/resolvers/ResolutionFileResolver.html

Comment: The resolution file handle is not what i am looking for... That takes a set of images based on a predefined resolution while in android the drawables are selected based on dpi... It is a big difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be my solution is not the best but I used it in real project and it worked.

In your `Game` class use `Gdx.graphics.getDensity()` method to choose appropriate folder, store its name in public field and load your assets:

```
public class MyGame extends Game {

public static String folder;
private AssetManager assets;

@Override
public void create() {
   if (Gdx.graphics.getDensity < 1) {
      folder = "lowDpiImages/";
   } else {
      folder = "highDpiImages/";
   }
   ...
   assets = new AssetManager();
   assets.load(folder + "image.png", Texture.class, paramsNearest);
   ...
}
```

Then in you other classes use folder name to get assets from `AssetManager`:

```
assets.get(MyGame.folder + "image.png", Texture.class);
```

You can write more sophisticated folder choosing algorithm of cause ;-)

Comment: This is very helpful. I just implemented this and seems to work fine. I have just one more question. I experimented with getDesnity method and I discovered that my density will be rounded. For example on 213 dpi it will be 240 dpi meaning 1.5 scale. Is this normal?

Comment: This is ok. Open this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density) and read about `public float density` in `Fields`. It's value is returned by `getDensity()` method for Android backend in LibGDX.